# How to display records with time interval

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a website i.e. I'm working on aspx pages. I am storing value in to the xml file.
I need to display value stored in xml at specified time interval (say 1 min) on a asp label. But not all records are to display at an instance. At first instance first record of xml and after time interval next record and so on. After last record again first record needed to display.

I Google search a lot on this but could not find specific solution on this.
Please help me with successful solution. Thanks...

This is my code but its not giving expected results. Please help me in editing this.

HTML code

```
<div>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>    
</td></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

ASPX coding

```
public partial class UpdateNews : System.Web.UI.Page
{
DataRow dr;
int i = 1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120).ToString();
//GetNewValue();
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
{
i++;
GetNewValue();
}
}
public void GetNewValue()
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("News.xml"));
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
if (i <= dt.Rows.Count)
{
dr = dt.Rows[i - 1];
Label1.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
}
else
{
 if(i > dt.Rows.Count )
 i = 1;
}
}
}
```

Comment: You can apply for loop on nodes what you want and iterate them using timer or Task.Delay(1000).

Comment: I used loop but not useful.
In a loop last value in xml file is set to label.
i want every value for particular time.
Also I have intializes counter to 1 but when Time interval completes the total page loads n instead to taking next value counter again stars from 1 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer now my code is running properly.
But now When I put my page in content page I get an new error :-(
Please help me I need to clear this error at its earliest due to my deadline.

It say: cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.label' at line 1
        Where line 1 is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.master" AutoEventWireup="true"               CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" Inherits="Home" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

My working code is here :

HTML Code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>  
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Title" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="News" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Counter" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName ="tick" /></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ASPX Code:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
DataRow dr;
int i = 1;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!ScriptManager1.IsInAsyncPostBack)
Session["timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(100).ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Counter.Text))
{
i = int.Parse(Counter.Text);
i++;
}
GetNewValue();
}

public void GetNewValue()
{
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("News.xml"));
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
if (i <= dt.Rows.Count)
{
dr = dt.Rows[i - 1];
Title.Text = dr["Title"].ToString();
News.Text = dr["Description"].ToString();
Counter.Text = i.ToString();
}
else
{
if (i > dt.Rows.Count)
i = 1;
Counter.Text = i.ToString();
}
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (0 > DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now,
DateTime.Parse(Session["timeout"].ToString())))
{
GetNewValue();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use time with update panel in asp.net web forms.
Following is the code :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate> 
    <!-- your content here, no timer -->
</ContentTemplate>
```

Things you want to do can be put in timer1_tick

Comment: I did this but in coding I am getting problem while counting records when time interval completes.

Comment: what problem you are getting.
Reading your senerio you need to put the last index of item you got from database into viewstate and when you try to get new item from item tick event you can get that value and get the next index value of that saved value and overwrite to viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

My code was correct
Just   error was I should not rename ID field of Labels in update panel.
I dont know why this happened.
But when I renamed my Title, counter,News label to label1 label2....
It worked properly and gave me my required result.

Thank you all for responding and trying to help me.